# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_74.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.9.5 and trying to compile code as mentioned in [Boost.StringAlgorithms](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.stringalgorithms).

I am getting the below error during local compilation and linking :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Boost.StringAlgorithms, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_74.lib'
1>Done building project "Boost.StringAlgorithms.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have ensured that I have set the project properties (link and libs). I do see the concerned file in **C:\tools\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib** directory:

```
libboost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib
boost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib
```

I have build all boost library for x64 architecture - why the linking process is looking for **libboost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_74.lib** ?